# Confusion with notion of "simple $R$-modules" and "simple submodules of regular $R$-module"

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I am a bit confused with these two notions; it arised while studying the following: given a ring $R$, a minimal left ideal of $R$ is a left ideal $L\neq 0$ such that, if $L'\subseteq L$ is a left ideal of $R$, then either $L'=0$ or $L=L'$. In other words, a minimal left ideal **is a simple submodule of the left regular module $_R R$.**

But then I have a theorem which says that, for a semisimple ring $R$, any simple $R-$module is isomorphic (as a module) to a minimal left ideal of $R$ and this somehow confused me. The point is that not all simple $R-$modules are simple submodules of $_R R$?

Could someone clarify these notions to me, please? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}$. The regular module $_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}$ has no simple submodule (minimal ideal) at all.

Even if the ring has minimal left ideals, it is not necessary that every simple module is isomorphic to a minimal ideal. For instance, consider the ring
$$
R=\mathbb{Z}\times A
$$
where $A$ is any abelian group; the operations are
$$
(m,a)+(n,b)=(m+n,a+b)
\qquad
(m,a)(n,b)=(mn,mb+na)
$$
The minimal ideals are the simple submodules of $_{\mathbb{Z}}A$, but $p\mathbb{Z}\times A$ is a maximal ideal for every prime $p$. So if you take $A$ the cyclic $2$-group, the ring has infinitely many simple modules that do not embed in the regular module.

On the other hand, if $R$ is semisimple, then every submodule of $_RR$ splits. Take a maximal left ideal $M$ of $R$; then $R\cong M\oplus(R/M)$, so the simple module $R/M$ embeds in $_RR$.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. All is clear now!